# Using a list in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, list, excel, vlookup

Using an Excel macro (VBA) I'm inserting the following formula into a worksheet.  Later in the code I paste over the formulas as values.

```
Firstrow = 2
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
  With .Range(.Cells(Firstrow, "A"), .Cells(Lastrow, "A"))
        .Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,Codes!$A$1:$A$14,1,FALSE))=TRUE,""YES"",""NO"")"
  End With
```

Is there a better way to just have the answers Yes or No entered into the cells in column A.  I would like the lookup list (Codes!$A$1:$A$14) to be inside of the macro instead of in one of the worksheets.  Thanks in advance for any help you might be able to send my way!  Jordan.

Comment: If the value is in the list then you want the cell value to equal `No`?  It's unclear what you are asking.  Do you want to the values from`Codes!$A$1:$A$14` to be in the macro and not on the worksheet?  Or do you want to lookup up the values from `Codes!$A$1:$A$14` with the macro and assidn `Yes` or `No` without using a formula?

Comment: @ThomasInzina Thanks for your reply.  I would like to add Yes or No directly to the cell instead of the formula and I would like the list to be in the macro, not on the worksheet.  If the value is in the list then I want the cell to say "No".  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Fill the `values` array in with the appropriate values from `Codes!$A$1:$A$14`.

### Code without comments

```
Sub UpdateLookups()
    Dim data, values As Variant
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim x As Long

    values = Array("Tom", "Henry", "Frank", "Richard", "Rodger", "ect...")
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = .Range("D2", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    data = Target.Value
    For x = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        data(x, 1) = IIf(IsError(Application.Match(data(x, 1), values, 0)), "YES", "NO")
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = data
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

### Code with comments

```
Sub UpdateLookups()
    Dim data, values As Variant
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim x As Long
    'values: Array of values that will be searched
    values = Array("Tom", "Henry", "Frank", "Richard", "Rodger", "ect...")
    'With Worksheets allows use to easily 'qualify' ranges
    'The term fully qualified means that there is no ambiguity about the reference
    'For instance this referenece Range("A1") changes depending on the ActiveSheet
    'Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1") is considered a qualified reference.
    'Of course Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1") is fully qualified but it is usually overkill

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'Sets a refernce to a Range that starts at "D2" extends to the last used cell in Column D
        Set Target = .Range("D2", .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    ' Assigns the values of the Target Cells to an array
    data = Target.Value
    'Iterate over each value of the array changing it's value based on our formula
    For x = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        data(x, 1) = IIf(IsError(Application.Match(data(x, 1), values, 0)), "YES", "NO")
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Speeds up write operations (value assignments) and formatting
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Speeds up write operations (value assignments)
    'Here we assign the data array back to the Worksheet
    'But we assign them 3 Columns to the left of the original Target Range
    Target.Offset(0, -3).Value = data
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Loading the data into an Array allows us to write the data back to the worksheet in one operation
    'So if there was 100K cells in the Target range we would have
    'reduced the number of write operations from 100K to 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Also I wanted to tell you I'm new to all of this and I'm taking the code you sent me and working with each line to teach myself what exactly it does.  I really appreciate the time all of you take to help out the newbies like myself.

Comment: Nice!  I didn't know (or realize I guess) that you could run `match()` with an array that only exists in the VBA macro. Will definitely be using that in the future.

Comment: @BruceWayne make sure to use `Application.Match` and `IsError`  because `WorksheetFunction.Match` throws a nasty error.

Comment: @JordanCA57 I added comments to my answer.

Comment: @BruceWayne you might be interested in [VBA Trick of the Week :: Slicing an Array Without Loop – Application.Index](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/)

Comment: @BruceWayne ROFLMAO!!! I got one more favorite article for you [Excel VLOOKUP vs INDEX MATCH vs SQL vs VBA](http://analystcave.com/excel-vlookup-vs-index-match-vs-sql-performance/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129666/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-thomas-inzina).

Answer (score 0):

Untested as no sample data but it would look something like this:

```
Firstrow = 2
Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
  With .Range(.Cells(Firstrow, "A"), .Cells(Lastrow, "A"))
        If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ThisWorkbook.Sheet(1).Range("D2"), ThisWorkbook.Sheet(Codes).Range("$A$1:$A$14"), 1, False)) Then
            .Value2 = "YES"
        Else
            .Value2 = "NO"
        End If
  End With
```

Please note that I have not scoped your range D2 properly as I don't know the structure of your Workbook or what the worksheet name is. Please adapt to your needs. Cheers,

Comment: The OP's uses a relative reference in his formula `D2`.  When it is filled across range the formula will increment with each row.  For example `Range("A2:A4").Formula = "=D2"` will result in `A2` formula = `=D2`,`A3` formula = `=D3` and `A4` formula = `=D4`.  The OP also wants the lookup values in the subroutine and not in `Codes!$A$1:$A$14` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

an [Autofilter()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) approach, with no loops

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array("a", "b", "c") '<--| set your lookup list
    With Worksheets("MyData") '<--| change "MyData" to your actual worksheet with data name
        With .Range("D2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column "D" cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
            .Offset(, -3).Value = "YES" '<--| write "YES" in all corresponding cells in column "A" ("NO"s will be written after subsequent filtering)
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter referenced cells with lookup list
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(, -3).Value = "NO" '<--| if any filtered cell then write "NO" in their corresponding column "A" ones
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```